# How to set up a Java server to communicate with a website

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, server

I have made a local Java server that communicates with a local HTML web page. The Java server runs with GlassFish on Eclipse mars. (I am using HTML5's websocket class to make the two communicate with each other). Everything is working well. Now, I want to put my website on a domain (so not localhost), but I still want the Java server to interact with the webpage. Of course, this is not possible since the java server is running locally. I tried looking for this but I could not find it: how can I set up a (Java) server that can communicate with a website (which is just not running locally)? I am new to this, so any help is appreciated!

(I have a computer which can be set up as a server).

Thank you

Comment: You need to install java on whatever machine hosts your webpage. If your computer can be a server, just link your domain name to it and you're done.

Comment: @takendarkk I am sorry, but could you specify a bit. How can I link domain name to the Java class?

Comment: Your server should answer to requests on a port. Register your domain with a DNS provider and point to the static ip and port of your home machine.

Comment: Ok, so then what edits do I have to make to my Java class (the one which is for the server, running on GlassFish)? The java script code is this: var websocket = new websocket ("my domain name");    But what changes do I have to make to the java server class so that my javascript can call it because obviously, I won't be needing GlassFish anymore

Comment: You don't connect to a java file. You connect your domain to Glassfish, THAT'S your server. It can send requests to whatever class you want.

Comment: Another question. Can I use a web hosting service to host me Java classes? Instead of using my server, can I link my html/JavaScript webpage with my Java classes using a web hosting service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93419/discussion-between-user5139637-and-takendarkk).

Comment: Yes, if they install any application server like glassfish, tomcat, jboss, websphere, etc...